# Why my lazyColumn is only loading when I go to a different fragment and back in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this list I am getting from Firebase and displaying in a LazyColumn but it only works when I navigate to a different fragment and press back. My lazyColumn is being composed inside de ScreenController for the bottomNavigation.

What do I have to do to display it directly?

below is my Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class OpenTicketFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: OpenTicketsViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {

                val ticketsList = viewModel.tickets.value.data

                val currentUserId = viewModel.currentUserId.value

                TheProjectTheme {

                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    val title = remember { mutableStateOf("Open Tickets") }
                    val isDialogOpen = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                    Scaffold(

                        topBar = {

                            TopAppBar(
                                navigationIcon = {
                                    IconButton(onClick = {
                                        isDialogOpen.value = true

                                    }) {
                                        Icon(Icons.Default.ExitToApp, contentDescription = null)
                                    }
                                },
                                title = {
                                    Text(text = title.value)
                                },
                                actions = {
                                    IconButton(onClick = {
                                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_openTicketFragment_to_profileFragment)
                                    }) {
                                        Icon(Icons.Default.Person, contentDescription = null)
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        },
                        bottomBar = {

                            val items = listOf(
                                Screen.Open,
                                Screen.Available,
                                Screen.Closed
                            )
                            BottomNavigation {
                                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                                val currentRoute =
                                    navBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getString(KEY_ROUTE)

                                items.forEach {
                                    BottomNavigationItem(
                                        icon = { Icon(it.icon, contentDescription = null) },
                                        selected = currentRoute == it.route,
                                        label = { Text(text = it.label) },
                                        onClick = {
                                            navController.popBackStack(
                                                navController.graph.startDestination, false
                                            )
                                            if (currentRoute != it.route) {
                                                navController.navigate(it.route)
                                            }
                                        })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    {

                        ScreenController(
                            navHostController = navController,
                            title,
                            ticketsList!!,
                            findNavController(),
                            currentUserId
                        )
                        AlertDialogComponent(isDialogOpen, findNavController(), viewModel)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OpenTicketLazyColumn(
    ticket: Ticket,
//    onClick: () -> Unit,
    navController: NavController,

) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .clickable {
                val action =
                    OpenTicketFragmentDirections.actionOpenTicketFragmentToTicketDetailFragment(
                        ticket.ticketId,
                        ticket.problem,
                        ticket.address,
                        ticket.dateOpened,
                        ticket.description,
                        ticket.name,
                        ticket.status
                    )
                Log.d("SSS8", ticket.ticketId)
                navController.navigate(action)
            },

        elevation = 4.dp

    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .weight(1f)

            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Ticket Opened Date: ${ticket.dateOpened}",
                    fontSize = 16.sp,

                    )
                Text(
                    text = "Service required: ${ticket.problem}",
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                )
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .weight(1f)

            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Status: ${ticket.status}",
                    fontSize = 16.sp,

                    )
                Text(
                    text = "Address: ${ticket.address}",
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my composables

```
@Composable
fun ScreenController(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    topBarTitle: MutableState<String>,
    ticketList: List<Ticket>,
    navController: NavController,
    currentUserId: String
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController, startDestination = "open"
    ) {
        composable("open") {
            Log.d("SACO", currentUserId)
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
                items(items = ticketList) { item ->
                    val status = remember { mutableStateOf(item.status)}
                    if (status.value == ASSIGNED && item.assignedToId == currentUserId) {
                        OpenTickets(
                            item,
                            navController
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            topBarTitle.value = "Open Tickets"
        }
        composable("available") {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
                items(items = ticketList) { item ->
                    val status = remember { mutableStateOf(item.status)}
                    if (status.value == OPEN) {
                        ClosedTickets(
                            item,
                            navController
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            topBarTitle.value = "Available Tickets"
        }
        composable("closed") {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
                items(items = ticketList) { item ->
                    val status = remember { mutableStateOf(item.status)}
                    if (status.value == CLOSED && item.assignedToId == currentUserId) {
                        AvailableTickets(
                            item,
                            navController
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            topBarTitle.value = "Closed Tickets"
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OpenTickets(
    ticket: Ticket,
    navController: NavController
) {

    OpenTicketLazyColumn(
        ticket,
        navController
    )
}
```

the viewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class OpenTicketsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WorkerRepositoryImpl,
    private val firesource: FireBaseSource
) : ViewModel() {

    val currentUserId = mutableStateOf("")

    val tickets: MutableState<DataOrException<List<Ticket>, Exception>> = mutableStateOf(
        DataOrException(
            listOf(),
            Exception("")
        )
    )

    init {

        getAllTickets(listOfServices)
    }



    private fun getAllTickets() {
        viewModelScope.launch {

            val ticketsList = repository.getAllTickets().data
            tickets.value.data = ticketsList

        }
    }
```

the firebaseSource

```
class FireBaseSource @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore
) {
   
 suspend fun getAllTickets(
        listOfServices: List<String>
    ): DataOrException<List<Ticket>, Exception> {
        val dataOrException = DataOrException<List<Ticket>, Exception>()
        try {
            dataOrException.data = firestore.collection(TICKETS)
                .whereEqualTo(PROBLEM, ELECTRICIAN)
                .get()
                .await().map { document ->
                    document.toObject(Ticket::class.java)
                }
        } catch (e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
            dataOrException.e = e
        }
        return dataOrException
    }
}

 1. List item
```

Comment: What is `viewModel.tickets.value.data`? Please include your ViewModel.

Comment: How does this code interact with Firebase? I highly recommend reproducing the problem in isolation, instead of copy/pasting snippets from your actual app. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on this and more hints that will drastically increase the chance that someone can help.

Comment: I updated the code with the viewModel and the firebaseSource